# Get text between two identical lines in Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

i'm totally new to Python. I use Perl a lot and heard that Python was often better at parsing text so I wanted to give it a try, but I can't figure out the easiest way to do this (For info, I already did it in Perl, but it took me several, slow and ugly loops):

I want to read a big file and extract blocks of text that are between two lines that start by the same pattern, exemple :

```
!NAME: "N0",                DESCR: "Netnt Etrnet"
!NAME: "cp0",              DESCR: "Cle R0"
!NAME: "slt R1",               DESCR: "RSt"
>>!NAME: "moe R1",             DESCR: "ASessor 1,bps"
>>!PID: A9-55
>>!VID: G0984981
>>!SN: SEDGH25443N51E
!NAME: "SDFGSDFG: FGT/0",       DESCR: "VFDFGX1"
!NAME: "JQFHF1",       DESCR: "VNQDF2"
```

Of course the ">>" aren't part of the text file, it's just to show what lines I want to retrieve.

So to recap : I want to print ALL the blocks (there are more of them in the file) where the first line of the block starts by "!NAME" and has other lines before the next "!NAME".

I don't care about blocks where there is two "!NAME:" in a row.

This is just the first step, later I will try to retrieve values of this block to create an hash (or dictionary or whatever is the equivalent of an hash in python). But I'm already stuck at the first step so i'm asking for help haha.

Thanks !

Comment: python is better than perl at many things.  Parsing text is not one of them.

Comment: Perhaps you should change the way to do it in Perl.

Comment: Perl is excellent for processing text. That's almost its raison d'être

Comment: I get the comment that say Perl is doing good at processing text. Indeed it is and I never said otherwise. I said that I HEARD (from collegues etc.) that python can sometimes be better. So I wanted to give it a try. I don't get the downvote really...

Comment: That's what i'm doing right now. I'm taking a script I made in perl (which might not be optimized to the max, I agree), and try to convert it to Python. I'll do that with a couple more, that way I'll see by myself if one is better than the other (in my opinion) to do different kind of stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    prev = ""
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith("!NAME:"):
            print(prev.rstrip())
            print(line.rstrip())
            for line in f:
                if line.startswith("!NAME:"):
                    prev = line
                    break
                print(line.rstrip())
                prev = line
        prev = line
```

If you want each section stored, you can use a dict:

```
from itertools import count

from collections import defaultdict
cn = count()

sections = defaultdict(str)
with open("log.txt") as f:  
    prev = ""
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith("!NAME:"):
            key = next(cn)
            sections[key] += prev
            sections[key] += line
            for line in f:
                if line.startswith("!NAME:"):
                    break
                 sections[key] += line
                 prev = line
        prev = line

print(d)
defaultdict(<class 'str'>, {0: '!NAME: "moe R1",             DESCR: "ASessor 1,bps"\n!PID: A9-55\n!VID: G0984981\n!SN: SEDGH25443N51E\n'})
```

To make sure you only find sections that have a preceding !Name, make sure the previous line started with !Name:

```
with open("log.txt") as f:
    prev = ""
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith("!NAME:") and prev.startswith("!NAME:"):
            key = next(cn)
            sections[key] += prev
            sections[key] += line
            for line in f:
                if line.startswith("!NAME:"):
                    break
                sections[key] += line
                prev = line
        prev = line
```

Comment: It appears the OP wants the first `!NAME` according to their `>>`'s in the post

Comment: @JonClements, yep, I knew I had prev there for some reason originally!

Comment: Thanks, At first glance I think it's what i'm Looking for, even tho I got and error (print(prev.rstrip())
NameError: name 'prev' is not defined). I'll try to solve it and once I will i'll validate your answer :)

Comment: @user2407268, there is a line before  the first time we see `!Name` so prev is never defined, I added  `prev = ""` but using that logic there is a section that is not preceded by  a `!Name` line

Comment: Yes Indeed, the file is not just a big block of lines that start with !Name, there is a ton of other differents lines. I just extracted the part that i though was relevent. But you're right I just tested it, and it also displays the lines before the !Name. I'll try to think of a solution, I'll validate your code because it's still the answer of what I asked for. I just asked something too specific for the case i'm in :)

Comment: do you only want lines that follow `!Name` or all lines?

Comment: I don't care about the part of the file before and after the section where there a all the lines that start by !Name. I'll try to adapt your code, it'll be a good practice to learn a bit about Python :)

Comment: @user2407268 feel free to check out an itertools approach as per my answer :p

Comment: @JonClements, are you trying to hijack my imaginary reputation points? ;)

Comment: @Padraic hahaha... don't you know that all your imaginary internet points belong to me? :p (On a more serious note, I did `@` the OP to have a look, but it was mostly because I thought you'd find it an interesting way of doing this...)

Comment: @JonClements, +1 anyway even after attempting to rob me in blind daylight :P

Comment: Haha thank you both for your help, and yes i will defe... difen... define... definitely look at your code, any additional knowledge is useful :)

Comment: @Padraic it's only because we miss you in chat :)

Comment: @JonClements, chat is far too complicated for my simple mind :)

Comment: Hey, thanks I saw you updated your code. It's super clear :-) Except for the key = next(cn) thing. I didn't understand what it meant. Would you mind explaining ? Thanks !

Comment: It it an iterator, every time we call `next(cn)` we increment the count, 0,1,2.... It allows us to increment different keys for each value and do it sequentially.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can use `itertools`.

- Ignore everything in the file until the first `!NAME`
- Group by whether the line starts with `!NAME` or not
- Group that into pairs where the first pair is the `!NAME` line and the second pair is everything up until the next `!NAME` or EOF
- Include in the output the last item of the `!NAME` lines, where it's followed by at least one line that isn't a `!NAME`

Code:

```
from itertools import groupby, izip_longest, dropwhile

with open('inputfile') as fin:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in fin)
    start_at = dropwhile(lambda L: not L.startswith('!NAME'), stripped)
    grouped = (list(g) for k, g in groupby(start_at, lambda L: L.startswith('!NAME')))
    for name, rest in izip_longest(*iter([grouped] * 2), fillvalue=[]):
        if rest:
            print name[-1]
            print '\n'.join(rest)
```

Gives:

```
!NAME: "moe R1",             DESCR: "ASessor 1,bps"
!PID: A9-55
!VID: G0984981
!SN: SEDGH25443N51E
```

Comment: @user2407268 haha... fair enough... wasn't understanding what you meant anyway... maybe just describe the logic you're trying to implement?

Comment: New comment because old one was ugly, I didn't realize I couldn't indent text in here. So basically you made a dropwhile function to start only when !Name appears, but since later in the file there are lines I want to ignore, I replaced it by ---  takewhile(lambda L: L.startswith("!Name","!VID","!PID","!SN"), stripped) ---- problem is I got an error saying that startswith takes 3 arguments max. Any idea to force the 4th argument anyway ?

Comment: @user2407268 `str.startswith` takes a tuple - eg `L.startswith(('!Name', '!VID', '!PID', '!SN'))`....

Comment: @user2407268 I fear that'll break the logic though... the above is relying on ignoring every until the first "!NAME", then pairing up the is a name/not a name together... so while I'm still not sure exactly what you're trying to do - be careful with that one ;p

Comment: Umm.... are you always looking for Name VID PID SN in sequential lines?

Comment: Nope. Sometimes there is no VID line for exemple. But you're right I want to group the name, vid, pid, and sn together so what I did might break the logic. I'm still trying to understand your code completely that's why I'm having some difficulties at telling the loop to stop if there in no more !NAME after the last !SN of the file

Comment: The blocks always start by a !Name and ends with a !SN on the other hand. Only the PID or VID line can be missing. That's why I wanted to find a way to stop printing lines if there is no !Name after a !SN

Comment: @user2407268 so the logic is `!NAME` -> `!SN` are groups? eg: the end of a  group is `!SN` - not the start of a new `!NAME` or EOF ?

Comment: If by !Name -> !SN you include whatever lines there might be between !Name and !SN, then yes.
Just saw your edited comment. Exactly. The end of a group is !SN, not a new !NAME or EOF